# Return (not print) all permutations of a string Java

Tags: java, string, recursion

There are dozens of questions on "find the permutations of a string" but all of their answers are printing the permutations. I want to create a method that takes an input string and returns a List containing all the permutations.

Here is my code:

```
    public static List<String> allPerms(String str){
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        while(!allPerms("", str).equals("")) {
            results.add(allPerms("", str));
        }
        
        return results;
    }
    
    private static String allPerms(String perm, String word) {
        if(word.length() == 0)
            return perm;
    
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            String small = allPerms(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1));
            return small;
        }   
    }
```

But this gives me an error saying that the for loop of my private method is dead code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: For one thing, you're returning before the loop will complete--as soon as the first `allPerms` within the loop completes you return from the loop. That makes the loop unnecessary.

Comment: loop with recursion. Check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795527/how-recursion-works-inside-a-for-loop

Comment: First problem you should look at is, that your method doesn't compile, because, it doesn't return String in all the cases. What happens when your for loop finalizes?

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code, let's walk through them one by one. The function `allPerms(String perm, String word)` contains two issues: a missing return statement and the i++ dead code:

```java
private static String allPerms(String perm, String word) {
    if(word.length() == 0)
         return perm;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) { 
        String small = allPerms(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1));
        return small; // <- if you return here the loop will only iterate once, so i++ is dead code.
    }   
    // <- missing a return statement here
}
```

We can fix it like in the following:

```java
public static String allPerms(String perm, String word) {
    if(word.length() == 0)
        return perm;
    String small = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        small = allPerms(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1));
    }   
    return small;
}
```

Now there are no compilation errors but the result is not correct. In fact, if you run it you will get an infinite loop. The reason is because the method `allPerms(String str)` exits the while-loop only if the `allPerms("", str)` method returns and empty string which is never true! (unless you call `allPerms("")`)

```java
public static List<String> allPerms(String str){
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    while(!allPerms("", str).equals("")) { // <- infinite loop because never true
        results.add(allPerms("", str));
    }
    
    return results;
}
```

So you need the following changes to get the list of permutations:

```java
public class Main {
    public static List<String> allPerms(String str) {
        return allPerms("", str);
    }
    
    public static List<String> allPerms(String perm, String word) {
        if (word.length() == 0) {
            return Arrays.asList(perm);
        }
        List<String> small = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            small.addAll(allPerms(perm + word.charAt(i), word.substring(0, i) + word.substring(i + 1)));
        }
        return small;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(allPerms("abc")); // Prints: [abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba]
    }
}
```