# How to set value in nested array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, tree, nested

I would like to set `level` to each array that has `children` key in nested array. More deep that array then more big the level value.

Here's what I'm expected:

```php
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 6,
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 7,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 8,
                    )
                ),
                // Expected
                'level' => '2',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 9,
            )
        ),
        // Expected
        'level' => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 10,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 13,
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 14,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 19,
                        'children' => array(
                          array(
                              'id' => 20,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 21,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 22,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 23,
                          ),
                        )
                        // Expected
                        'level' => '3'
                    )
                ),
                // Expected
                'level' => '2'
            ),
        ),
        // Expected
        'level' => '1'
    )
);
```

So far I make a function to set the level that has `children` key in nested array. But, the result is not what I'm expected.

```php
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 6,
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 7,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 8,
                    )
                ),
                // Expected
                // 'level' => '2',
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 9,
            )
        ),
        // Expected
        // 'level' => '1'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'children' => array(
            array(
                'id' => 10,
            ),
            array(
                'id' => 13,
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'id' => 14,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'id' => 19,
                        'children' => array(
                          array(
                              'id' => 20,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 21,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 22,
                          ),
                          array(
                              'id' => 23,
                          ),
                        )
                        // Reality result
                        // 'level' => '4'
                    )
                ),
                // Reality result
                // 'level' => '3'
            ),
        ),
        // Reality result
        // 'level' => '2'
    )
);
```

As you can see in **Reality result** comment is level 2, level 3, and level 4. What I'm expected the result is level 1, level 2, level 3, level (n+1). When there's not any children in the deeper array then the level value must be reset to level 1.

Here's my code that get the reality result:

```php
<?php
function updateTreeArray(&$array, $level = 1) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
        if (isset($value['children'])) {
            $value['level'] = $level;
            $level = setLevel($value['children'], $level);
        }
        
        if (is_array($value)) {
            updateTreeArray($value, $level);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

function setLevel($array, $level) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
      if (isset($value['children'])) {
        $level += 1;
        setLevel($value['children'], $level);
      }
    }
  
  return $level;
}
  
print_r(updateTreeArray($array));
```

Could you please help me what should I do to achieve the expected result? Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR imho,  in your `setLevel()` function you're missing something like `$array['level']=$level;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One recursive function is enough.

```php
function updateTreeArray(&$array, $level = 1)
{
    foreach($array as &$item) {
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item) && is_array($item['children'])) {
            $item['level'] = $level;
            updateTreeArray($item['children'], $level + 1);
        }
    }
}

updateTreeArray($array);

print_r($array);
```

[fiddle](https://3v4l.org/Lpr6k)

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Comment: Thanks @ser14717238! It works and really appreciate. One more thing that I don't understand is how can $level reset to be 1 again after moving to array with `'id' => 2`

Comment: This is a recursive calling technique. The function call at each iteration of the loop waits for its result and remembers all the values of the variables at this level of the call. And so on every nested call. Therefore, there may be insufficient memory for too large a call depth. [How Recursion Works Inside a For Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795527/how-recursion-works-inside-a-for-loop/4795566)